# Spring MVC multi-part configuration

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-upload, upload

Trying to write a simple file upload handler using Spring MVC 6.0.6. A file is uploaded using `POST`, with encoding `multipart/form-data`. On the server side, the handler is

```java
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@Controller
@MultipartConfig
public class SimpleUpload {
    @PostMapping(path = "/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(@RequestParam("File") MultipartFile file) {
        return file.isEmpty() ?
                new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) : new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Getting this error: `Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided`.

I have read other answers about this error, so I have added the multi-part configuration as follows:

```java
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@Import({ApplicationConfig.class})
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public MultipartResolver getMultipartResolver() {
        return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    }
    @Bean(name = "filterMultipartResolver") // alternate name suggested by some people
    public MultipartResolver getFilterMultipartResolver() {
        return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    }
}
```

It does not seem to work, because the error is always the same.

The unit test in the application is successful:

```java
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MvcConfig.class, SimpleUpload.class })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MultipartPostRequestControllerUnitTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Test
    public void whenFileUploaded_thenVerifyStatus() throws Exception {
        MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("File",
                "hello.txt",
                MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE,
                "Hello, World!".getBytes());

        MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                .build();
        mockMvc.perform(multipart("/upload")
                .file(file))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

But sending a file via Postman to http://127.0.0.1:8080/upload returns an HTTP status 500, with root cause `Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided`.

How can I fix this?

Using Tomcat 10.1.7 to run the app.

Answer (score 4):

As you have moved to spring 6 so it will use `jakarta.servlet-api`. Also, you have used spring-mvc so you have to do configuration in **web.xml** file to let the servlet know it needs to support multipart request. `@MultipartConfig` will not work with web.xml.

You need 1 bean for `StandardServletMultipartResolver`.

```
@Bean
MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
}
```

You need to update `web.xml` add `<multipart-config />`

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <multipart-config /> <!-- Add for supporting multipart request -->
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Docs of spring `MultipartResolver` recommend to set multipartConfig of servlet in method `customizeRegistration`, but it's called only for default DispatcherServlet in `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.onStartup`

So if `onStartup` is overriden, then you need to `setMultipartConfig` on servlet yourself:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    super.onStartup(servletContext);

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext restContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    restContext.register(RestServletConfig.class);
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic restEntryPoint = servletContext.addServlet("rest-servlet", new DispatcherServlet(restContext));
    restEntryPoint.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    restEntryPoint.setAsyncSupported(isAsyncSupported());
    restEntryPoint.addMapping("/");
    
    long maxSize = 10L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    restEntryPoint.setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement(null, maxSize, maxSize, 0));
    ...
}
```

and also multipartResolver in spring context

```
@Bean
MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
}
```